# Adjusting xaxis in plot.xts

Tags: r, quantmod

I want to zoom into the chart. The chart from the code below use data from 2007 to 2019. I will like to look at the chart only from 2012 to 2015. Does anyone know how to do this?

I have tried with `xlim = ("2012-01-01";"2015-01-01")`, but that did not work.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AAPL")
plot.xts(AAPL[,6])
```

Comment: One of the buttons when you write or edit your questions helps format the code so it's easier to read, as I've done here. Why do you have a semicolon in `xlim`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just to subset your xts-object to zoom it:

```
xts_data <- AAPL[ , 6]
xts_zoom <- xts_data['2012/2015']
plot.xts(xts_zoom)
```

The reason why setting `xlim` manually does not work is that the `xlim` values are calculated inside the `plot.xts()` itself. See, for example, the rows 123-134 of the `plot.xts()` source code:

```
   if (cs$Env$observation.based) {
        cs$Env$xycoords <- xy.coords(1:NROW(cs$Env$xdata[subset]))
        cs$set_xlim(c(1, NROW(cs$Env$xdata[subset])))
        cs$Env$xstep <- 1
    }
    else {
        xycoords <- xy.coords(.index(cs$Env$xdata[cs$Env$xsubset]), 
        cs$Env$xdata[cs$Env$xsubset][, 1])
        cs$Env$xycoords <- xycoords
        cs$Env$xlim <- range(xycoords$x, na.rm = TRUE)
        ...
    }
```

Another option is to use the built-in zoom tools of the `quantmod` package itself:

```
chartSeries(xts_data)
zoomChart('2012/2015')
```